# Inheritance models and foreign key

Tags: python, django

How to display if I add `Apartament` and `Land` object also `Contact` form and `Photo` form?

```
class Property(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    slug = models.SlugField()
    desc = models.TextField()

class Apartament(Property):
    bedrooms = models.IntegerField()
    levels = models.IntegerField()
    something = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Land(Property):
    something = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Contact(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    property = models.ForeignKey(Property)

class Photo(models.Model):
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='images')
    property = models.ForeignKey(Property)
```

admin.py:

```
class PhotoInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Photo
    can_delete = True

class ContactInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Contact
    can_delete = True

class PropertyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [PhotoInline, ContactInline, ]
```

This work only if I add Property object.

Comment: What is the question here? Make it clear.

Comment: How to create StackInline also if I add `Apartament` and `Land` object(for now it work only if I add `Property` object)

Answer (score 1):

Admin(inline)s are not symmetrical, you'll need to register admin classes for those models too including the inlines you require.